# Do checkboxes need unique id's, names and labels to have their CSS background toggled?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

**Desired Behaviour**

I have 35 tables containing 6 checkboxes each.

I am using this CSS in order to style their `checked` and `unchecked` states:

http://www.csscheckbox.com/checkbox/20695/paperclip-style-thin-css-checkbox/

When using more than 1 instance of a table, the CSS only seems to work (ie apply the correct `checked` and `unchecked` states) when each checkbox has a unique name, id and label.

I want to achieve the same effect without having to type a unique name, id and label for all of the 210 checkboxes in the 35 tables.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/8edb0j0g

**What I've Tried**

In the example below I have shown 2 table instances where each checkbox has a unique name, id and label.

Giving them the same "identifiers" prevents functionality, as does removing them altogether.

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* from:  
http://www.csscheckbox.com/checkbox/20695/paperclip-style-thin-css-checkbox 
*/

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1000;
  left: -1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
  padding-left: 22px;
  height: 17px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 17px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  font-size: 17px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
  background-position: 0 -17px;
}
label.css-label {
  background-image: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_a1e28825bac3d82a32f547300c847628.png);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1" id="checkboxG1" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG1" class="css-label">area 01</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG2" id="checkboxG2" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG2" class="css-label">area 02</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG3" id="checkboxG3" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG3" class="css-label">area 03</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG4" id="checkboxG4" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG4" class="css-label">area 04</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="checkboxG5" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG5" class="css-label">area 05</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG6" id="checkboxG6" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG6" class="css-label">area 06</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- second table here -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG7" id="checkboxG7" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG7" class="css-label">area 01</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG8" id="checkboxG8" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG8" class="css-label">area 02</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG9" id="checkboxG9" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG9" class="css-label">area 03</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG10" id="checkboxG10" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG10" class="css-label">area 04</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG11" id="checkboxG11" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG11" class="css-label">area 05</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="area_checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG12" id="checkboxG12" class="css-checkbox" />
      <label for="checkboxG12" class="css-label">area 06</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be useful for you if I briefly describe what trickery is being employed here. The unstyled checkbox is being hidden because its associated label is placed over the top of it. Checkboxes have functionality built in where if you click their associated label they become toggled on, so by clicking the label with the fake checkbox image, you're able to toggle the hidden checkbox on. There's CSS rules to change the fake checkbox image based on whether the hidden checkbox is checked or not.

So the answer to your question is ... sort of. You don't need the name field if you just want the toggle effect, but that's what's referenced when you do a form submission, so you probably will need it later.

The ID on your checkbox is necessary because the ID field is what the label's `for` attribute references, and you need a relationship between the label and the checkbox as I previously mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Certain fields are inherently unique; names, id's and label names. You are never supposed to have more than one element with the same name/id/label.

While you could assign more than one checkbox a duplicate of any of these fields, it would be bad practice to do so; it would be an attempt to use an identifier in a way that it is not intended to be used.

In the case that you have multiple elements requiring the same styling properties, classes are then used. Classes are meant to be used in the case that you want to reuse certain styling properties.

---

Imagine this scenario:
You have two identical checkboxes...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG6" id="checkboxG6" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkboxG6" class="css-label">area 06</label>
 .......
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG6" id="checkboxG6" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkboxG6" class="css-label">area 07</label>
```

In this case, the HTML and CSS are both looking for a unique name/id/label. But that truly doesn't exist. How is it supposed to know which one you are referencing? It can't make this decision and therefore neither of them is assigned the styling properties. That is why the fields **must** be unique.

---

### Suggestion Going Forward

If you don't want to manually set each checkbox, I would check out [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). It makes doing tasks like this ***extremely*** easy; you can define rules and use pre-existing directives in your HTML that make it extremely hassle-free.

In AngularJS, you could do something like the following: [AngularJS Checklist-model](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)

Comment: Angular seems like a bad suggestion. He's clearly trying to not rely on JavaScript by going for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: @Michael He never mentions a "pure CSS" solution, actually. He says that  he doesn't want to type a unique name/id/etc for each checkbox. This is where Angular excels

Comment: Not explicitly but he's using a website which specifically provides pure CSS checkbox styles.

Comment: Yeah, but he isn't talking specifically about the CSS. His question is about typing out the fields and values for each of the 210 checkboxes. BTW, the site also provides a javascript version.

Comment: @Michael You say to-may-toe, I say to-mah-toe.

Comment: You could equally argue that he could just generate it in a PHP for loop. No overhead in making the client download anything that way.

Comment: @Michael If that's your suggestion, feel free to add it to your answer.